# How to create thumbnails with a fixed width, so all of them will have the same width?

Tags: images, customization, post-thumbnails

right now, a thumbnail will be *either* 150px in height *or* in width, depending if it's landscape or portrait. Is there a way to make them always the same width and scale them in height accordingly, without squaring them?

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`add_image_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) in your `functions.php`:

```
add_image_size( 'post-icon', 150);
```

...and then use this in your template:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('post-icon'); ?>
```